# represent hankel matrix by low rank tensorial approximation

Tags: matrices, tensor-products, svd

suppose that we have  given following matrix

\begin{matrix}
  x_1 & x_2 & ..x_p \\
  x_2 & x_3 & ...x_{p+1} \\
 . & .& . &  \\
  x_{N-p+1} & x_{n-p+2} &... x_n
       \end{matrix}

where  $N$ is length of  $x$ vector,namely $x={x_1,x_2,..x_N}$

and $p$ is parameter   chosen such that $1<p<N$,we can represent  given matrix by following  tonsorial approximation

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{min(p,l)} \lambda_i*(U_i  \bigotimes V_i ) $

this represent tensorial approximation of original matrix,where  $U_i$ and $V_i$ are  singular vectors  from this matrix and $\lambda_i$ is  singular value,in this case we are taking columns of singular  matrices,my question is following how can i express each $x_i$,that is $x={x_1,x_2,...x_N}$ from this formula?in my mind  $x_1$ will be  first element of matrix  got by sum of all this matrix,this will be  for $x_p$ as well,but what about $x_{p+1}$ ?can you help me please to finish this formula?

UPDATED : for instance

```
>> a=[2 1 3;1 2 3];
>> a

a =

     2     1     3
     1     2     3

>> [U E V]=svd(a);
>> x1=kron(U(:,1),V(:,1));
>> x2=kron(U(:,2),V(:,2));
E(1,1)*x1+E(2,2)*x2

ans =

    2.0000
    1.0000
    3.0000
    1.0000
    2.0000
    3.0000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A=USV^T$ is an SVD of a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, then 
$$\tag{1}
a_{ij}=e_i^TAe_j=e_i^TUSV^Te_j=\sum_{k=1}^r(e_i^TUe_k)(e_k^TSe_k)(e_k^TV^Te_j)=\sum_{k=1}^r s_k u_{ik}v_{jk},
$$
where $s_k$ is the $k$th diagonal element of $S$ and $r$ is the rank of $A$.

This is true for the "exact" SVD, not necessarily the truncated one as of course the truncated SVD approximation of $A$ is not equal to $A$. It also does not need to have the Hankel structure unless $A$ is square (and hence symmetric).

Comment: but let us suppose that  for truncated it happens

Comment: @datodatuashvili Ok so in that case, the first paragraph can be easily adapted to your problem.

Comment: i have question how can be represented  $x_{p+1}$ if  for example $p$ is less then $l$?

Comment: @datodatuashvili What is $l$?

Comment: $l$ is $N-p+1$,it is another dimension of matrix,we have dimension $p$ by $N-p+1$

Comment: In your notation, $a_{ij}=x_p$ if $i+j=p+1$, so $x_p$ is, say, $a_{p,1}$. Then plug it into (1).

Comment: but at $p+1$  singular values are zero right?because if i took  $p$ as dimension,it should have $p$ singular values

Comment: Since the matrix is $l\times p$, there's no singular value $p+1$. The matrix $S$ has the same dimension as $A$ (in the full SVD). There are as many (nonzero) singular values as is the rank of $A$, which cannot be larger than $\min\{l,p\}$.

Comment: ok thanks very much for your help